# Azure Blob Trigger Not Firing

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-function-app, azure-blob-trigger

I am creating an Azure Blob Storage Trigger which is supposed to run every time a new file is dropped into the blob.

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "blob/{blobname}.{blobextension}",
      "connection": "PROPER_CONNECTION_STRING_IS_HERE"
    }
  ]
}
```

Once I upload this to my function app though, nothing happens when I drop a file in the blob. When I run the code/test portion of the function app, I am able to confirm that the code exists and runs. The problem is that it doesn't run automatically when I drop a file into the blob.

Comment: You are dropping file into blob container?

Comment: Did you put the connection string directly in this position? `connection": "PROPER_CONNECTION_STRING_IS_HERE`

Comment: It is recommended to use Event Grid instead of Blog Trigger based on this scenario, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp , have you considered that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the information you gave, I think you might write the `connection string` directly after the `connection`.

If you develop in the cloud, you should write `connection string` in `app setting`.

[image]

Then you need to add the configured variable name to the back of the `connection`.

[image]

If your approach is the same as above, then I suggest you to check if the `path` in your `Function.json` is configured correctly.

Or as `Akash` mentioned in the comments, if you use a `blob-only account`, or if your application has specialized needs, you can use [Event Grid trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp#alternatives).

If it has not solved your problem, please give more information and I will try my best to help you solve this problem.